# Conditional based on the results returned by $resource promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, promise

I am calling my api through angularjs and returning a list of 'reports' to angular through the $resource promise. Based on whether any results were returned I want to either show a modal with the report information or successfully save the sale.

I have spent some time pulling my hair out over this and was hoping some people here might be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks guys!

Below is my attempt, however it saves the sale regardless of whether the promise is returning reports or not. So i would assume there is something wrong with my conditional. I have tried a few variations but with no success.

```
$scope.reports = Scammer.findScammerById({hfid: sale.buyer_hf_url}).$promise.then(function (reports) {
      if ($scope.reports.length > 0) {
        $scope.alertScammer(reports, 'md');
      } else {
        sale.$save(function (u) {
          console.log(u);
          $scope.sales.push(u);
          $scope.totalIncome += u.sold_for;
          $scope.weeklyEarnings += u.sold_for;
          $scope.monthlyEarnings += u.sold_for;
          $scope.totalSales++
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: I thing to share a bit more context. If the `sale` is saved it means that `$scope.reports.length is empty`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I am receiving results in the array from $resource. I have checked in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to change $scope.reports to just reports. Facepalm